# convert from array to JSON

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm tried to convert javaScript array to JSON.
the javaScript array is full of details but the JSON is empty.
This is how I did the convert:

```
var jsonToDB = JSON.stringify(msgToDB);
```

I want to insert this array to mongoDB and because of this I did the convert to JSON.

This is how the array looks in debug (before the convert):

```
images: Array[1]
0: "vghbjn.jpg"
messageName: "ghjk"
millisecToShow: 1000
screenId: Array[1]
0: "screen1"
template: "Template1"
text: Array[1]
0: "vhbjnk"
timeFrame: Array[1]
0: Object
date: Object
end: "June 25, 2014"
start: "June 25, 2014"
days: Array[2]
0: "Sunday"
1: "Saturday"
time: Object
end: Object
hour: "23"
minutes: "00"
seconds: "0"
start: Object
hour: "00"
minutes: "00"
seconds: "0"
```

and the JSON is empty: jsonToDB: "[]".

Comment: This is impossible to answer, if the array had content you would get that content as a JSON string, so the array is probably empty when you're stringifying it, and there's no way for us to tell you why !

Comment: try `console.log(msgToDB)` then inspect the result in the console.  Is it empty there?

Comment: More information would be required to have any hope of answering.

Comment: The array is not empty. I'd write the content in it (as it shown in debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified my code with your original data, and it also worked fine. Don't know how you're getting the issue.

```
var msgToDB = {
"messageName": "1",
"text": [""],
"images": ["image1.jpg"],
"template": "template.html",
"millisecToShow": 100,
"timeFrame": [{
    "date": {
        "start": "January 1, 2014",
        "end": "December 31, 2014"
    },
    "days": ["Sunday", "Saturday"],
    "time": {
        "start": {
            "hour": "6",
            "minutes": "0",
            "seconds": "0"
        },
        "end": {
            "hour": "7",
            "minutes": "0",
            "seconds": "0"
        }
    }
   }],
  "screenId": [1]
  };

var jsonToDB = JSON.stringify(msgToDB);
console.log(jsonToDB);
```

And here is the JSFiddle link:- http://jsfiddle.net/Gk3e5/

Comment: The array is look like this:
{
    "messageName" : "1",
    "text" : [""],
    "images" : ["image1.jpg"],
    "template" : "template.html",
    "millisecToShow" : 100,
    "timeFrame" : 
    [
      {
        "date" : {"start" : "January 1, 2014", "end" : "December 31, 2014"},
        "days" : ["Sunday", "Saturday"],
        "time" :  {
                    "start" : {"hour": "6", "minutes": "0", "seconds": "0"},
                    "end" : {"hour": "7", "minutes": "0", "seconds": "0"}
                  }
      }
    ],
    "screenId" : [1]
  }

Comment: I've modified my code and it also worked fine. Can you check if there is any difference between your code and mine.